# Maven dependency graph

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way to have a Maven dependency graph of a given set of projects (if possible, graphical), without having 3rd party dependencies drawn too? Or where I opt out the dependencies I'm not interested in?

I'd like to point the tool/plugin at a number of POM files and see a description of the dependencies between those projects.

Comment: If you are using eclipse, you have a `dependencies` view on which you can graphically exclude dependencies.

Comment: This view is only for a given project, I'd like to have the view of the relationships between my projects

Comment: did anyone try https://github.com/janssk1/maven-graph-plugin/wiki/Manual?

Answer (score 52):

If you use `mvn dependency:tree`, you can specify files to exclude or include with `-Dexcludes` and `-Dincludes`. The output is an ASCII-art style depiction of the dependencies.

See the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) for more info.

Comment: But this is just for a given project, is it not ? I'd really like to see the relationship between my projects.

Comment: Something like this (http://mvnplugins.fusesource.org/maven/1.0/maven-graph-plugin/), but apparently this one doesn't offer to opt out the 3rd parties

Comment: @Simhor So you want to point at a number of POM files and see a graph of the relationships between those projects?

Comment: Alternatively the program could just infer the submodules, just by giving the top pom.xml

Answer (score 34):

there exists exactly what you need, it is called **Pom Explorer**.

You can find the website here : [github.com/ltearno/pom-explorer](https://github.com/ltearno/pom-explorer)

It is a tool to work on a graph of maven projects. As a teaser i can say that on my machine it analyzes 4000 pom.xml files in 4 seconds. Then many functionnalities are provided above the analysed pom graph :

- dependency analysis (who depends on GAV, which gavs this GAV depends on, with transitivity),
- resolution (pom explorer knows where are defined properties, it manages dependencies and bom imports),
- manipulation (you can use it to transform you pom graph, let's say if you want many projects to use a new version of a dependency),
- build (pom explorer analyses your pom graph and knows in which order they should be built, then it builds everything ! it can even watch your projects directories for change),
- exporting (today there is CSV and a GRAPHML exports),
- visualization (pom explorer can show you an interactive 3D customizable visualization of your projects graph).

It is in active development right now so don't hesitate to try it, report bugs and ask for useful features ! The documentation is also not complete yet, so again don't hesitate to ask !

Thanks

Comment: Nice tool, can you explain what needs to be done to simply get a graph of dependencies for a given set of maven projects? So far I can analyze the folder containing the set of projects and list all gav with pom-explorer. What do I need to do to get a graph of dependencies between those projects (without 3rd parties) for further processing. What I want is to just have a simple graphs between the maven projects to know how to build the project in the right order.

Comment: You can use the `graph export [gav_filter]` command to export a graphml file representing your projects. And then you can filter it with yEd for example.
If you like the 3d WebGL graph command (graph), you can then filter teh displayed GAVs directly in the graphical interface.
Maybe best to post this question as a documentation issue on the github project, so that other people can benefit...https://github.com/ltearno/pom-explorer/issues

Comment: Sorry, but the gui is cumbersome. Is there a command line way to use the tool?

Comment: The gui tries to be command line like. For the moment there is no other choice. Expect maybe to write a little command line wrapper around the pom-explorer.jar

Answer (score 13):

```
mvn com.github.ferstl:depgraph-maven-plugin:aggregate -Dincludes=com.yourcompany.pkg
```

Does well for me.

Comment: The best I tried so far, but it gets fooled by compile/test dependencies. A dependency with 'test' scope by default, overriden as 'compile' is a subproject is not taken in account. Some dependencies may appear several times.

Answer (score 5):

I like [depgraph-maven-plugin](https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin) to visualize dependencies in a multi-module project, see also [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53174258/757308).

To get an aggregated result in text format (like `dependency:tree`) for your modules, use:

```
mvn com.github.ferstl:depgraph-maven-plugin:aggregate -DgraphFormat=text -Dincludes=myGroupId
```

The syntax for includes is the same as with [maven-dependency-plugin includes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#includes).

It has a lot of [properties to customize the result/behavior](https://ferstl.github.io/depgraph-maven-plugin/aggregate-mojo.html). I prefer to use it together with [graphviz](https://graphviz.org/download/), so I can use the (default) graph format `dot` and let it create a `png` file in the `target` folder:

```
mvn com.github.ferstl:depgraph-maven-plugin:aggregate -DcreateImage -Dincludes=myGroupId
```

There are also other interesting [goals](https://ferstl.github.io/depgraph-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html), e.g. an `example` goal to quickly play around with the properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [POM2RDF](https://github.com/AtomGraph/POM2RDF) to generate an RDF graph of your project dependencies (and their dependencies, and so on) that you can then query to get a Software Bill of Materials or visualize as a dependency graph.

Disclaimer: I'm the author.